# iOS : Specifying unix time in NSDateFormatter's format string

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, date-format, unix-timestamp

I receive date in this format **"/Bla(1344433014807)/"** in server's response.
1344433014807 is a number of seconds from the 1 January 1970.

Also I have this code in my network engine that I use :

```
NSDateFormatter* dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

**Question:** how can I specify correct dateFormat to get date from dateString like @"/Bla(1344433014807)/" or even is it possible?

**Note:** In engine I don't have access to manipulate with dateString. I can set dateFormat only.

Answer (score 3):

[Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has the solution for your query

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:123456789];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

The /Bla part is unnecessary value passed alongwith the actual epoch time i.e. 1344433014807. Unix time is The Unix epoch is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 (or 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z ISO 8601). Refer [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number)

Comment: Thanks. I know it. My question is: Is it possible to use NSDateFormatter to get NSData from string with format that I specify.

Comment: Thanks again.
But I need retrieve date in that way that i wrote :
NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString:dateString];
And format of dateString must be something like "/Bla(x)/", where x - is a number of seconds from the 1 January 1970. Is it possible?

I understand that correct way is retrieve value 123456789 from string and then use NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:123456789];

But I use some engine that retrieves dates in way that I wrote in the question.
And things that i can do is only specify dateString format that will be used by engine.

Answer (score 0):

From [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW4) on the Apple documentation, you can see `NSDateFormatter` follows the [Unicode Technical Standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), and from there you can see that specifying unix time is not an option.

So you'll have to split the string, convert the number to an NSTimeInterval, to read it into an NSDate.

http://unixtimestamp.com is very helpful in debugging this. You'll notice that **1344433014807 is actually milliseconds**.

Here's a Swift implementation since I ended up having to write it myself, hopefully it works correctly :)

```
public func dateFromBlaString(string: String) -> NSDate? {
    if let rangeOfDate = string.rangeOfString("^/Bla\\(", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil, locale: nil)
        where count(string) >= count("/Bla(") { // avoid out of range error
            let startIndex = advance(string.startIndex, count("/Bla(")
            let suffix = string.substringFromIndex(startIndex) // "1344433014807)/"
            if let parenthesisRange = suffix.rangeOfString(")", options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) {
                let parenthesisIndex = parenthesisRange.startIndex
                let unixTimeInMillisecondsString = suffix.substringToIndex(parenthesisIndex) // "1344433014807"
                if let unixTimeInMillisecondsDouble = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(unixTimeInMillisecondsString)?.doubleValue { // 1344433014807.0
                    let unixTime = NSTimeInterval(unixTimeInMillisecondsInt) / 1000
                    return NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTime)
                }
            }
    }

    return nil
}
```